# generic XML from select query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to get this XML from "select * from ANY_TABLE" query?

```
<root>
    <row>
        <column name="id" value="321">
        <column name="name" value="Book">
    </row>
    <row>
        <column name="id" value="654">
        <column name="name" value="Pen">
    </row>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to get the result you want.

```
declare @T table(id int, name varchar(20))

insert into @T values(321, 'Book')
insert into @T values(654, 'Pen')

select (
         select 'id' as '@name',
                T.id as '@value'
         for xml path('column'), type
       ),
       (
         select 'name' as '@name',
                T.name as '@value'
         for xml path('column'), type
       )
from @T as T
for xml path('row'), root('root')
```

If you want this to work for any table using `select *` you can use this instead.
Just replace `@T` with whatever your table name is. Note: this will only work if the column names are valid XML element names.

```
select 
  (
    select T3.N.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname') as '@name',
           T3.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as '@value'
    from (
           select T1.*
           for xml path(''), type
         ) T2(N)
      cross apply T2.N.nodes('*') as T3(N)       
    for xml path('column'), root('row'), type
  )         
from @T as T1
for xml path(''), root('root')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to transform what you get with FOR XML you may consider to use XSLT.

Comment: It's a pretty big topic! You may start at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171950.aspx

Comment: looks like sql server does not have XmlTransform function and I cannot use CLR here.

Comment: Can't use CLR? Client side conversion?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Declare @Temp Table(Id Int, Name VarChar(20))

Insert Into @Temp Values(321, 'Book')
Insert Into @Temp Values(654, 'Pen')

Select  (
            Select 'id' as '@name', 
                    id as '@value' 
            From   @Temp As B
            Where A.Id = B.Id
            FOR XML Path('column'), Type
        ),      
        (
            Select 'name' as '@name', 
                    Name as '@value' 
            From   @Temp As B
            Where A.Id = B.Id
            FOR XML Path('column'), Type
)
From    @Temp As A
FOR XML path('row'), Root('root')
```

Notice that this code use a temp table variable so I could dummy up some data.  It should be relatively easy to modify this to use your actual table.

Comment: thank you, it works but does not for my situation. the only problem with it that it knows about 'Id' and 'Name' columns.  I want to find a way how to convert select * from ANY_TABLE to that format.

Comment: There is no need to use `from @Temp` in your sub queries. You can query the fields directly using alias `A`. You will avoid two table scans.